# Difficult Limit Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I am asked to evaluate $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac {2y}{h^3}e^{-\frac{y^2}{h^2}}$$
Any hints or help would be appreciated. My hunch is it is uniformly zero or equivalent to a Dirac delta function, but I have had difficulty arriving there rigorously.

Comment: Not a proof but certainly a useful 'check': http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B2y%2Fh%5E3+Exp%5B-y%5E2%2Fh%5E2%5D,h-%3E0%5D

Answer (score 3):

If $y\not=0$ (otherwise the limit is trivially zero), let $x=(y/h)^2$ then
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac {2y}{h^3}e^{-\frac{y^2}{h^2}}=\frac{2}{y|y|}\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {x^{3/2}}{e^{x}}=0.$$
For the last step you can use Hopital's rule two times:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {x^{3/2}}{e^{x}}=
\frac{3}{2}\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {x^{1/2}}{e^{x}}
=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {x^{-1/2}}{e^{x}}=0.$$

Comment: Ah, good idea with squaring in order to make $x$ approach only positive infinity. +1 for the interesting solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $t=1/h$ and rewrite the limit in terms of $t$ instead of $h$.  After that it is straightforward with L'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

You may just conclude that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac {2y}{h^3}e^{-\frac{y^2}{h^2}}=0$$ there isn't much rigour to show here; all you could do is simply state that the $$e^{-\frac{y^2}{h^2}}$$ dominates over the $\dfrac{1}{h^3}$ factor as $h\to 0$ and hence the integral is trivially equal to zero. Since the $$e^{-\frac{y^2}{h^2}}\to 0$$ much faster than the $\dfrac{1}{h^3}\to \infty$.